# SIM5300E Shield Strange readings on COM port

Tags: at-command, 3g, com-port

Recently I purchased [this](https://www.banggood.com/3G-SIM5300E-Development-Board-GSM-GPRS-GPS-SMS-Data-3G-Network-Speed-Module-p-1278648.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN) SIM5300E shield and have been having trouble interfacing with it. I connect the debug USB port to my computer and connect to the com port via PuTTY. The responses to AT requests can be seen in the image.

Responses on COM Port to AT commands:
[image: Responses on COM Port to AT commands]

[image: Responses on COM Port to ATS commands]

[image: Hex Code]

This is not due to baud rate as I have tried many different ones and I always get the "SIO:" message after the AT command. I have also tried other COM ports but they do not output anything

Comment: Check your line terminator settings. In fact "normal" chars are rendered correctly; what is strange is line terminator. Just to be sure: what is the output if you provide `ATS3?` and `ATS4?`

Comment: I am not sure where to find the line terminator settings. I have added another image with the output of `ATS3?` and `ATS4?`.

Comment: I have switched terminals to CoolTerm and now can change the line terminator settings.

Comment: Does the output change?

Comment: The output does not appear to be changing significantly e.g the SIO message appears even after changes. In the picture I have added I was changing the line terminator at regular intervals.